# Django - CreateView - Send a custom Error Message if model form is not valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have some Class Based Views where I use [the Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/messages/)
to send a success_message if the form POST `is_valid`.

I would also like to send a custom `error_message` if the form POST is not valid.

It was very obvious how to configure the `success_message`, just use the SuccessMessageMixin and
add a "success_message" variable. I have tried the same approach for an
error_message, but none one of my attempts showed
the error flash message on the form page - my attempts are commented out below in the `else:` block.

Sending an error message to a CBV seems like something that would be a pretty common scenario, yet I cannot find any examples in the Django docs or anywhere else online.

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

> Just to be clear - I am not  talking about adding ValidationErrors
> that are created for specific fields. I have ValidationErrors for fields working fine. This
> refers to a custom flash message that would be present at the top of the
> page.

```
#views.py

class DocCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): 
    model = Doc
    form_class = DocForm
    template_name = "doc/doc_form.html"
    context_object_name = 'doc'
    success_message = 'Doc successfully created!'
    error_meesage = "Error saving the Doc, check fields below."
    

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_submit(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('doc-detail'))
        else:
            # messages.error(self.request, error_message)
            # messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, error_message)
            # form = DocForm()
    
        return redirect('doc-detail', pk=post.pk)
```

#base.html

```
      {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert {% if message.tags %}alert-{{ message.tags }}{% endif %}">
             {{ message }}<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

      {% block content %}
      {% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the [**`form_invalid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_invalid) to add an error message:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class DocCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): 
    model = Doc
    form_class = DocForm
    template_name = "doc/doc_form.html"
    context_object_name = 'doc'
    success_message = 'Doc successfully created!'
    error_message = 'Error saving the Doc, check fields below.'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('doc-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: thanks for the response - that seems like an obvious solution. unfortunately, I am unable to get it to work - When I put your code in i get an AttributeError
Exception Value:  'DocCreateView' object has no attribute 'error_message'

Comment: @stevec: in your question, you made a typo in `error_message` (not `error_meesage`)

Comment: Hah! when i miss something like that, I know I've been staring at my screen for too long! Thank you, that fixed the issue. time to go to bed.

Comment: ```messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)``` change to ```messages.error(self.request, form.errors)```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put message adding in `form_submit`, something like that:

```
#views.py

class DocCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView): 
    model = Doc
    form_class = DocForm
    template_name = "doc/doc_form.html"
    context_object_name = 'doc'
    success_message = 'Doc successfully created!'
    error_meesage = "Error saving the Doc, check fields below."
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_submit(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DocForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('doc-detail'))
    
        return redirect('doc-detail', pk=post.pk)
```